# How to best handle database in android?

Tags: android, performance, static

I have an android DB Adapter class defined like this:

```
public class DBAdapter
{                 
    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_PORTF);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SERIES);
        }

        public void reset(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_PORTF);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_SERIES);
            onCreate(db);
        }       
    }

    // actual table stuff comes here.
```

Now, later in the code, in some other class, I loop over different items and for each item I need to update a table in the database. I could think of two ways to do this:

```
void updateDatabase(item) {
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    // update tables, rows, whatever
    db.close();
}

for (Item item: myItems) {
     updateDatabase(item);
}
```

Or I could do it this way:

```
void updateDatabase(db, item) {
    // update tables, rows, whatever
}

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();
for (Item item: myItems) {
     updateDatabase(db, item);
}
db.close();
```

My guess is that the second way is the way to go. But in this case I have to pass on the `db` object not just one level, but three. Or is there another way handling this an 'easy' and efficient way? (By 'easy' I mean avoiding lines of unimportant/administrative code).

Comment: Personally, I use the first way since it keeps my activity/fragment class code clean and tidy.

You can also open the db in onCreate and close it in onPause or onDestory

Comment: Also also would prefer to use the first code. But does it impact performance badly? I do not know how this is handled behind the scenes,,,

Comment: I don't see any reason to open and close the db each time. I would go with the second solution since it seems much more affective to open it once, making your changes, and then close it.